# sharing rules on case object in salesforce

Tags: security, permissions, salesforce, sharing

I have a sharing rule on a case when createdbyid = specific user for a spastic role. the role just has one user assigned to it. The user's profile that is on the role has Read, Create, Edit, Delete permissions on case object.There's no permission set assigned to this user. I'm trying to log in as the role user and the case record page is blank. I created a case record from the user and I can't see it I just get this blank page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIJED.png)

Comment: Did I miss something, or did you not say what programming language your using?

Answer (score 1):

Can the user see the Case in another way, for example on listview / report / searching for the Case Number in global search? Normally you'd get a meaningful error, not blank page.

Console is notoriously bad at trying to be helpful and caching pages, maybe you need a hard refresh (Ctrl+R), maybe check if there are any JavaScript errors (some custom component that fails to load?).

Maybe you need to recalculate the sharing rules? Sometimes they get stale, try clicking the button in Setup -> Sharing settings -> Case. Your sharing rule references user record id ("005...") or "FirstName LastName"?

If you flip the UI to Classic and navigate to the case record as admin - check what's in the [Sharing] button (it might not be present, in which case add it to page layout). You should see high level info but also option to expand the view, see in detail who can see/edit this record (highest access level) and why. Use this to experiment with the sharing rule and view results as admin, withotu having to log in back and forth.